# Word order for the "es gibt" construct in subordinate clauses

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause

How does the "es gibt" construct behave when it is in a subordinate clause?

For example, let's start with a simple:

> Es gibt einen Hund.

Now let's move it into a subordinate. Some alternatives I could think of

> Ich glaube, dass einen Hund gibt.
>   Ich glaube, dass es einen Hund gibt.

Is any of those correct?

Comment: None is. "Es" is the subject, hence "Hund" can't be in the nominative case.

Comment: First, @Peasant is right but I think that's not part of the question. So I changed "ein" to "einen". Second, I think in your first "Ich glaube, ..." sentence is missing the "es". I don't know where you did want to put it; however, the second sentence is already correct (provided having the correct declension).

Comment: Actually, the answer to this question is pretty easy. You just move the verb to the end of the sentence, and you're done. There's nothing special just because using "es gibt".

Comment: Oh, I thought something strange could happen, like in the "passive without subject", where es only appears if necessary to keep the verb in position 2: "Es wird getanzt" -> "Morgen wird getanzt". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct is:

> Ich glaube , dass (subordinating conjunction) es (subject) einen Hund ("direct object") gibt (verb).

Pertaining to OP's comment on the question:

This "es" is not to be confused with the "es" we see in sentences like the following:

> Es wird in Deutschland viel Bier getrunken.
>
> Es muss mindestens einer von euch hier bleiben.

In these cases "es" is really only a filler and has no grammatical role whatsoever.... only a syntactical.